# Data retrieval with conditional SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, date, conditional-statements

**What is the best way to implement conditional data retrieval (in Oracle)?**

**Scenario:** An entity can have `delivery dates` and `confirmed delivery dates`.

Data retrieval should either

1. Return the next delivery date, if any date in the future (or today) remains.
2. Return the youngest delivery date, if all dates have passed.

Further constraints:

- If both, delivery date and confirmed delivery date are set, return confirmed delivery date.
- Each entity has a flag `important` that will make its delivery dates important (relevant, if two entities have the same delivery date and are compared).

The delivery date and the confirmed delivery date are stored in different columns.

**Question:** What is the best way to retrieve a delivery date in compliance with (1) and (2)?

I wonder, if this can be done in pure SQL at all (esp. the `IF..ELSE` part). I do want to query dates for single entities, but I also want to return lists of entities that are ordered by their date. Would I be better off writing a stored procedure?

Comment: I have used synonyms to effect that.  Create synonym based on conditions and then use thereafter.

Comment: Mind me asking, how can a ``SYNONYM`` be of any benefit for me here? From what I have read, its just an alias.

Comment: Sorry - did not read it correctly. Why don't you use a case statement?  You can use case, e.g. SELECT case
when n_numb = 1 then v_status := 'very small'
 when n_numb < 4 then v_status := 'small'
else v_status := 'very large'
end case;

Comment: Do you think you could post what your table(s) look like?

Comment: Perhaps if you want us to be able to suggest useful solutions to you, rather than just writing out your requirements, you could also provide your table structure(s), some sample input data, and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Syntax:

```
CASE column_value_to_check_value 
    WHEN condition THEN condition_match_value
    WHEN another_condition THEN condition_not_match_value
    ELSE default_value 
END
```